# Read lines from std input using Rust

Tags: rust

Hi I want to be able to read a file which contains json lines into a rust app like this

```
$ cargo run < users.json
```

and then read those lines as an iterator. As of now I have this code but i don't want the file hard coded but piped into the process as in the line above.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};


fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open("users.json")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in reader.lines() {
       
       println!("{}", line);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

I just solved it this makes the trick

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you would call you app like this `myapp < users.json` then this piping would be essentially made by the operating system and the file's content would be in stdin of your application, just read it as from console.

Comment: However in case of `cargo run` I'm not sure that cargo forward files content into your app. You can try to read from `std::io::stdin`, maybe you'll get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        println!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cargo help run` reveals:

```
NAME
       cargo-run - Run the current package

SYNOPSIS
       cargo run [options] [-- args]

DESCRIPTION
       Run a binary or example of the local package.

       All the arguments following the two dashes (--) are passed to the binary to run. If you're passing arguments to both Cargo and the binary, the ones after -- go to the binary, the ones before go to Cargo.
```

So to pass arguments the syntax would be:

```
cargo run -- foo bar baz
```

You can then access the values like this:

```
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
```

A complete minimal example would be:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    dbg!(&args);
}
```

Running `cargo run -- users.json` would result in:

```
$ cargo run -- users.json                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/sandbox users.json`
[src/main.rs:5] &args = [
    "target/debug/sandbox",
    "users.json",
]
```

Comment: I tryied without success
$ cargo run < users.json
and 
$ cargo run -- users.json

Comment: @Ro. I added an example for you :-)

Comment: This isn't reading from stdin, it's reading the arguments passed to the application.